# Why can't I place an Adview after a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, adview

I'm testing an `Adview` on my layout. If I place the `Adview` before the `ListView` everything is fine but if I place it after the `ListView` it just doesn't show up.

What's wrong?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxx"
        ads:testDevices="xxxx" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set the `ListView`'s `layout_height` to `fill_parent`, so it will take all the remaining vertical space in the layout. Your `AdView` is there, it was just displaced out of the screen by the `ListView`.

If you want to place the `AdView` at the bottom, and have the `ListView` take all the remaining vertical space, you can do it with weights:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: Great! Thanks @K-ballo, I'd tried that code but I thought I had to use it on the AdView. Works fine now.

Comment: this works to arrange the UI, but as soon as an Ad is loaded and shown the ListView scrolls to the bottom of the data :-(

Comment: `android:transcriptMode` should be disabled :-) now it's no longer scrolling

Answer (score 2):

your `Listview height is fill parent` so your vertical space is already taken by listview,,,

so make Listview `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxx"
        ads:testDevices="xxxx" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout to `RelativeLayout` and add `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` in your `ListView`. I hope help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxx" />

</RelativeLayout>
```